# VideoObject правильно подготовить длительность видео в формате ISO 8601

Tags: php, дата, iso8601

Имеется длительность видео в секундах, а нужно преобразовать в формат:

```
 PT(часы)H(минуты)M(секунды)S
```

Нужно это для микроразметки VideoObject для поисковика Google.
Например:

```
PT1H38M31S
```

И я подумал что вот такое можно сделать форматирование:

```
echo date('\P\TH\Hi\Ms\S', 86399);
```

И если выполнить строку например вот здесь https://onlinephp.io/    ,то выдает все норм. Результат:

```
PT23H59M59S
```

Но если запустить на Open Server на компе, то выдает со смещением на пару часов. На хостинге такая-же история, только смещение другое. Я так понимаю автоматически смещается относительно часового пояса системного времени(локалки или хостинга). Можно конечно написать простую функцию, которая посчитает часы/минуты/секунды. Но интересно почему функция date выдает время со смещением?(основной вопрос) Может это можно как-то поправить? Каким способом лучше всего сделать такое преобразование? С точки зрения СЕО и самого стандарта лучше опускать не нужные части длины видео - например видео длится меньше часа нужно ли писать:

```
"duration": "PT00H59M59S";
```

Comment: Не надо пытаться комбинировать текущее время с длительностью, эти понятия имеют разный смысл и работают по-разному. Лучше возьмите например что-нибудь отсюда https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13301142

Comment: @andreymal Спс за ссылку. Я понимаю в чем разница date() выдает дату, а не длительность, но вон в одну строку с gmdate() выходит. Не хотелось бы в холивар "Все только по канону против Работает не трогай" влезать.

Answer (score 0):

Оказывается существует функция, которая работает как date(), только выдает время без смещения по часовым поясам это gmdate(). В результате строка времени для микроразметки выглядит так:

```
echo gmdate('\P\TH\Hi\Ms\S', 86399);
```

Comment: Наверное, вы уже сами догадываетесь, что это не очень хороший способ, раз в качестве примера выбрали 86399 — уже с 86400 начинается чепуха

Comment: Все так. Для видео не длиннее суток. Если длиннее, то добавить разряд. И лучше пользоваться кодами по ссылке, а это для понимания работы функции только.